# Polars scan_parquet; is there a way to get the number of files scanned?

Tags: python-polars

I have "scanned" a glob pattern of parquet files

```py
import polars as pl
df = pl.scan_parquet("my/files/*.parquet")
```

Is there a method to get the number of files included in the scan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

There's no way to extract that from your `df` but you can just do

```
import pathlib
[x for x in pathlib.Path('my/files/').glob("*.parquet")]
```